# DoctrineCacheBundle: I cannot undersatand the documentation for using it with redis

Tags: php, symfony, redis, symfony-3.3, predis

As I was looking the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/index.html) in order to figure out how to use it in order to Cache APi results.

I cannot understand how to setup the configuration in order to make it work with either redis or predis.

I tried the following con figuration:

```yaml
doctrine_cache:
    aliases:
      my_cache:  'redis'

    providers:
        redis:
          host: '%redis_host%'
          port: '%redis_port%'
          aliases:
            - my_cache
```

But as I was tryint to debug my container with:

```
php bin/console debug:container doctrine
```

I got the error:

> "host" is an unrecognized Doctrine cache driver.

I also tried the following configuration:

```
doctrine_cache:
    aliases:
      my_cache:  'redis'

    providers:
        redis:
          type: 'redis'
          host: '%redis_host%'
          port: '%redis_port%'
          aliases:
            - my_cache
```

With the very same error. Also on documentation is not very clear how to pass the configaration option. Futhermore as said [there](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/reference.html) both redis and predis are natively provided with the bundle.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the result of pasting code or your actual code, but you're mixing 2 spaces and 4 spaces for indentation in the configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First setup configuration for redis.

```
doctrine_cache:
    aliases:
        cache: "%cache_provider%"
    providers:
        redis_cache:
            namespace: "%redis_cache_keyspace%"
            redis:
                host: "%redis_cache_host%"
                port: "%redis_cache_port%"
       array_cache:
            type: array
```

Then, set parameters.yml:

```
cache_provider: array_cache
redis_cache_host: localhost
redis_cache_port: 6379
redis_cache_keyspace: [your_keyspace]
```

I created a RedisService:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache;

class RedisService
{
    private $cache;
    /**
    * RedisService constructor.
    * @param Cache $cache
    */
    public function __construct(Cache $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function insert($key, $value, $lifetime = null)
    {
        return $this->cache->save($key, $value, $lifetime);
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        return $this->cache->fetch($key);
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
        return $this->cache->delete($key);
    }

}
```

Add this lines services.yml

```
redis_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\RedisService
    arguments: ["@doctrine_cache.providers.redis_cache"]
```

And you can use it everywhere. Sample;

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
* @package AppBundle\Controller
* @Route("/")
*/
class RedisApiController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * @return object
    */
    public function getRedisService()
    {
        return $this->get('redis.service');
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/insert", name="insert")
    */
    public function insertAction(){
        $this->getRedisService()->insert('website', 'http://mertblog.net', 3600);
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/get", name="get")
    */
    public function getAction(){
        $webSite = $this->getRedisService()->get('website');
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/delete", name="delete")
    */
    public function deleteAction(){
        $this->getRedisService()->delete('website');
    }
}
```