# DoctrineCacheBundle: Flush cache via SYmfony route

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine, symfony-3.3

Over my Symfony project I use the DoctrineCacheBundle and I want when I visit http://example.com/api/cache/flush I want to uncache (flush) any cached key.

The sole reason is because I have applications that visit the url above in order to remove any cached result.

As far I searched the DoctrineCacheBundle uses a command in order to uncache the cached results (as you can see via `php ./bin/console list doctrine:cache` command):

```
Symfony 3.3.12 (kernel: app, env: dev, debug: true)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -e, --env=ENV         The environment name [default: "dev"]
      --no-debug        Switches off debug mode
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands for the "doctrine:cache" namespace:
  doctrine:cache:clear     Flush a given cache
  doctrine:cache:contains  Check if a cache entry exists
  doctrine:cache:delete    Delete a cache entry
  doctrine:cache:flush     [doctrine:cache:clear] Flush a given cache
  doctrine:cache:stats     Get stats on a given cache provider
```

But how can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to make your own Cache adapter by following one of theese 2 approaches:

## Approach 1: Use dedicated manager for uncaching:

```
namespace AppBundle\CacheManagers;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FlushableCache;

class PurgeAllcachesManager
{

    /**
     * @var FlushableCache
     */
    private $purgeCachingHandler=null;

    public function __construct(FlushableCache $purgeCachingHandler)
    {
        $this->purgeCachingHandler=$purgeCachingHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Method that does all the dirty job to uncache all the keys
     */
    public function uncache()
    {
        $this->purgeCachingHandler->flushAll();
    }
}
```

## Approach2: Do as Doctrine does:

```
namespace AppBundle\CacheManagers;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache as CacheHandler;

class PurgeAllcachesManager
{

    /**
     * @var CacheHandler
     */
    private $cacheHandler=null;

    public function __construct(CacheHandler $cacheHandler)
    {
        $this->cacheHandler=$cacheHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Method that does all the dirty job to uncache all the keys
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function uncacheAllKeys()
    {
        if(!method_exists($this->purgeCachingHandler) ){
          throw new Exception("You cannot empty the cache");
        }
        $this->purgeCachingHandler->flushAll();
    }

    //Yet another methods to handle the cache
}
```

Also have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013054/doctrinecachebundle-i-cannot-undersatand-the-documentation-for-using-it-with-re) for extra info on how to use it.